# How do you delay your approach during a penalty kick in FIFA 12?

Tags: fifa-12

In FIFA 12, during the penalty shootout the AI often delays its shot when taking a PK. The player stops 1 step before the ball, trying to force the keeper to move, and then shoots.

a) How can you do this?

b) Are there any other special moves for penalty shootout? I know `L1 + B` lets you chip the ball for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured it out by accident:

Press `B` (shoot) again while the player runs towards the goal.

This actually gives you some more time to aim properly, I find it easier to make aimed shots into the goal corners with that technique.